# A Regular Expression with a Conditional in Lookbehind

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

This is using the .NET regex engine.

I am attempting to use a conditional inside of a lookbehind clause.  When the expression is used outside of the lookbehind it behaves as I expect -- but when placed in the lookbehind, it has a different behavior.

Here is a simple example of the effect to try to duplicate the issue.

Matching:

```
good morning
```

with the regular expression:

```
(?<=(?(?=go)good|bad)\s)morning
```

yields no match.

When tried without the look behind:

```
(?(?=go)good|bad)\smorning
```

I get a match on "good morning"

By fiddling around, I discovered that the lookahead cursor location, when it is inside the lookbehind, is after the word "good":

```
(?<=(?(?=\smor)good|bad)\s)morning
```

This matches "morning".

My question is is this expected or some kind of bug?

Obviously this example is not real world - the problem that I was trying to solve when I stumbled on this issue is as follows:  The expression uses a conditional to determine the length of the next word, then uses two different sets of rules for matching on that word.  Similar to:

```
(?<=\s+(?(?=[^\s]{1,2}\s)[A-Z0-9]+|(?![A-Z]+\s)[0-9-A-Z/"']+))\s+matching\s+text
```

This matches the "matching text" only if a one or two letter word consisting of letters and numbers, or a longer word not consisting of only letters but can contain numbers, letters, slashes, dashes, quotes and apostrophes.

The following should match "matching text":

```
1 matching text
a matching text
```

It only matches on the first one, because the conditional evaluated to false (it was looking at the " matching" instead of "a") and the negative look ahead searching for a word consisting of all letters failed on the "a".

Further examples:

Must match "matching text":

```
123-1 matching text
9B matching text
15/16 matching text
"45" matching text
A matching text
AA matching text
A1 matching text
```

Must not match "matching text"

```
and matching text
" matching text
A- matching text
```

Comment: no it is a normal behavior. Don't forget that a lookaround is a "zero width assertion". Thus the current position is determined by characters (or other regex tokens) outside the assertion.

Comment: The conditional looks for the next word to start with "go" and then matches on the entire word "good".  So it is taking zero width assertion into account.  Note that it works when not inside a look-behind.

Comment: Please, could you provide multiple examples strings (that must succeed and fail) to clearly illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: Edited with further examples.  The business logic is trying to identify identifier numbers -- numbers that you might see in an address or apartment number.  It must allow words that consist of all letters - but these should be limited to no more than two characters.

Comment: But why do you have to do this in a lookbehind?  As you said, that's the only thing that makes it difficult.

Comment: The match that I am after isn't the number.  But these numbers are important in finding the text that I am after.

Comment: FYI I edited the answer in great detail to explain why `(?<=(?(?=go)good|bad)\s)morning` does not match "good morning", and added .NET code showing how a small tweak to this expression would work, and why.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think I understand the issue now.  The important difference between a conditional inside of a lookbehind and a conditional not inside a lookbehind is the timing of when the conditional is executed (or where the search cursor is at that point.

The example without a lookbehind:

```
(?(?=go)good|bad)\smorning
```

good morning

The conditional is run at the beginning of the search.  So the search cursor is before the 'g' in 'good'.

```
 good morning
^
```

So at this point the look ahead evaluates to TRUE since it sees matches on the 'go'

In the example with the lookbehind, the cursor is at a different location.

```
(?<=(?(?=go)good|bad)\s)morning
```

The search cursor finds the first required item in the text: 'morning'

```
good morning
     ^
```

The actual search cursor stays in place to consume 'morning' if it the lookbehind matches.  The lookbehind will use its own cursor to verify what is before 'morning' to determine if this 'morning' is a match.  The lookbehind states that there is a '\s' directly before 'morning' and indeed there is.  The temporary lookbehind cursor moves to the space:

```
good morning
    ^^
```

Now it gets to the conditional and runs the lookahead in the conditional statement.   At this point the lookahead is looking for 'go' but it sees ' morning'.  So the conditional fails.  The expression says to try to match on 'bad' (or dab backwards from the lookbehind cursor) but it sees good (or doog backwards from the lookbehind cursor).  So no match for 'morning'.

### Solution

Since the conditional is run at the end of the word of interest when it is in a lookbehind (instead of at the beginning of that word outside of a lookbehind), the secret is to reverse the conditional to a lookbehind instead of a lookahead:

```
(?<=(?(?<=good)good|bad)\s)morning
```

This actually matches on **morning**.  It look nonsensical in this example to look for a word and then match it - but it illustrates the concept.  In the real world case stated in the question, the solution looks like this:

```
(?<=(?(?<=\s\S{1,2})[A-Z0-9]+|(?![A-Z]+\s)[0-9-A-Z/"']+))\s+matching\stext
```

This looks for a word before matching text.  The conditional checks to see if it is a one or two character word.  If so, it should consist of only letters and numbers.  If not, it must not only consist of letters.  If this is met, it can consist of letters, numbers, dashes, slashes, quotes and apostrophes.

Two things changed:

1. Modified the conditional to be a lookbehind instead of a lookahead
2. I had to move the '\s' from the beginning of the lookbehind into the conditional, because the conditional is being processed before that space and it results in matching on the last one or two characters of the word instead of looking for a one or two character word.  That is a tricky issue, because when the expression is not in a lookbehind (for instance if you want the text in the lookbehind to be included in the match), this change messes up the match.

---

What follows is some more analysis of the original problem.  Enjoy!

@zx81 had an example that is actually better at illustrating what is going on.  This example has more cursor movement so it does help illustrate what is happening:

```
    (?<=(?(?=go)good|bad))\w+pher

badphilosopher    <-- 'philosopher' matches
goodgopher        <-- 'gopher' matches
badgopher         <-- no match
```

There is a big difference in this example because the \w+ is used.  So the regex engine immediately matches all the text in each example since the phrase has no white space and ends in 'pher'.

So for 'badphilosopher':

Lookbehind is run and the conditional is immediately run looking for 'go' but finds 'ba'

```
badphilosopher
^
```

The condition failed so it tries to match bad to the left of the cursor, but we are at the beginning of the phrase, so no match.

It checks again at these two cursor points because the '\w+pher' matches each time:

```
badphilosopher
  ^
```

But the lookbehind sees 'b' then 'ba'

When the cursor gets to:

```
badphilosopher
   ^
```

The conditonal again fails to find a 'go' (it sees 'ph') so it attempts to match 'bad' to the left of the cursor and finds it!  So there fore the \w+pher matches the philosopher text.

```
goodgopher
    ^
```

goodgopher matches in a similar way except that the conditional is successful.

```
badgopher
   ^
```

badgopher does not match because the conditonal is successful but 'good' is not found to the left of the cursor.

Putting a space in there really changes things up, because the /w+pher no longer matches the entire string.

```
    (?<=(?(?=go)good|bad)\s+)\w+pher

bad philosopher    <-- matches philosopher
good gopher        <-- no match
bad gopher         <-- matches gopher
```

In this case the cursor moves through the string until it can match \w+pher:

```
bad philosopher
    ^
```

At this point it starts to process the lookbehind -- and sees that a '\s+' is required to the left of the search cursor -- it finds this and moves the temporary lookbehind cursor over.

```
bad philosopher
   ^^
```

The conditional is run now and sees looking for 'go' at the temp lookbehind cursor but finds ' p'.  The failure means trying to match bad to the left of the temp lookbehind cursor and indeed it finds it there.

```
good gopher
    ^^
```

The 'good gopher' example gets to the conditional and sees ' g' so it fails and then looks for 'bad' to the left of the cursor and doesn't find it.  So this fails.

```
bad philosopher
   ^^
```

Similarly, 'bad philosopher' gets to the conditonal and finds ' p' and looks for 'bad' to the left of the cursor and finds it.  So it matches.

When run without the lookbehind, all of these examples match.  This can be rather counterintuitive - but you have to take the location of the cursors into account in the lookbehind.

Comment: `A regex-directed engine walks through the regex, attempting to match the next token in the regex to the next character.` **The next token** means from left to right, the lookarounds **BEFORE** morning. See [How a regex engine works](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html)

Comment: I'm sorry you feel this way.  Here is a quote about lookbehinds from the Regex Tutorial:  `Lookbehind has the same effect, but works backwards. It tells the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string, to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there.`  This is what I am basing my answer on.  If this answer is wrong, please point out the error.

Comment: Thank you for keeping the dialog open, I think I may see the source of the misunderstanding, perhaps a subtle point. Your quote is 100% compatible with what I am saying. I am saying that at position x in the string, the engine tries the regex from left to right. The lookbehind comes **before** morning. It does **not** match morning before attempting the lookbehind. At position x, it attempts the lookbehind, which does mean as you quoted temporarily looking back in the string. But the position stays position x. Only if the lookbehind matches do we step forward to match "morning".

Comment: I understand what you are saying and it could be a matter of implementation.  An engine would waste a lot of energy running the lookbehind at every point in a large set of data if the data did not contain the word 'morning' anywhere. I ran a test. I searched a large text (1.2MB~) for the word `\smorning`.  It took a few seconds and found 227 occurrences. About same time for `(?<=the)\smorning` with 188 occurrences.  When I replace all `morning` with `notmorning`, the search returns very quickly.  The time difference implies that it looks for the existence of the required bit, `morning`, first.

Comment: As it happens, there is a trace tool that comes with PCRE, a potent regex engine, and that I often use. At the bottom of my post, I have added the trace for the expression discussed, where you will see how the PCRE engine behaves exactly as I have been explaining. I am sure you will find it fascinating. This has been the standard for regex engines, but of course there is always a possibility that some engines that allow variable-length lookbehinds might be changing. Even if that were the case, to say that my answer was not correct is quite a stretch.

Comment: p.s. In addition to the comment of a minute ago: you have run tests and researched literature, which I respect. In light of this, I have withdrawn my replies from this morning, having somewhat cooled down after your somewhat dismissive comments. Please go have a look at the trace mentioned in my earlier comment (it is shown at the bottom of my post), you will love it.

Comment: As for the engine temporarily stepping backward in the string, while other engines jump back by the fixed number of chars of the lookbehind, apparently [.NET evaluates the lookbehind from right to left](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=6k7IfACN_P8C&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=.NET+lookbehind+right+to+left&source=bl&ots=CoNg7Iuu2I&sig=qIFLadKXupls8FcsZ4eGbYki9TA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GwNaU8epJsWdkwXdioGICg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=.NET%20lookbehind%20right%20to%20left&f=false) Interesting, but that doesn't answer the question of the internals (evaluating the lookbehind first or morning first).

Comment: Regex God JG said: `In .NET, when RegexOptions.RightToLeft is not set, (?<=good)morning is processed from left to right just like any other regex.  So (?<=good) is attempted first.  But the contents of this lookbehind are processed right-to-left.  So "d" is attempted first, going backwards in the subject string.  If that matches, "o", "o", and finally "g" are attempted while going backwards in the subject string.  When the lookbehind succeeds the matching position is reset to what it was before the lookbehind was attempted.  Then "morning" is attempted as usual from left to right.`

Comment: Concerning the trace, you can tell that the lookbehind isn't being evaluated until the +4 -- it's clear that it knows that the lookbehind is looking for 3 characters and so it doesn't bother with trying what's inside until it gets to the point where 3 characters are to the left.  A variable-length lookbehind would not be able to make the same judgement - it would have to run the conditional at every step.  This may be where engines diverge, because that would be extremely inefficient.  I will see what I can find as far as a .NET trace.

Comment: Okay, another way to look at this. There are two issues here: 1. what is the advertised behavior of .NET regex? 2. what are the internals? You are now focusing on question #2. Your original question was "the engine is broken, it is not matching x". I conclusively showed you that the engine in fact is producing the expected result (#1, advertised behavior). As long as the advertised behavior is adhered to, whether or not the engine does things differently for optimization purposes is irrelevant to whether my answer is correct. There are tons of optimizations in regex engines. [to be continued[

Comment: [continuing] Do you see how, because of this difference between advertised behavior and internal optimization, it is really bad faith if you keep maintaining that my answer is incorrect? In the case of your question, the .NET engine perfectly adheres to the advertised behavior of every regex engine, i.e., matching tokens from left to right, whether these tokens are literals, conditionals, lookbehinds and so on.

Comment: We are arguing semantics here. At the end of the day, the engine ends up at the same location and processes the conditional.  So the original question about why the difference of behavior when a conditional is inside or outside of a lookbehind is the location of the search cursor when the conditional is executed.  Without the lookbehind, the conditional is executed immediately with the search cursor at the beginning of the pharse.  Within the lookbehind, the conditional is executed (perhaps not for the first time, but for the first time successfully) at the left edge of the matching phrase.

Comment: Sorry, I posted before I saw your response.  The reason I am saying your question is not correct is this:  `If what immediately follows is "go" i.e. (?=go) then immediately match "morning"`.  A conditionals format is (?(?=if)then|else).  So the intent of the conditional is if is sees 'go' it should match 'good'.  If not it should match 'bad'.  Being inside a lookbehind has the effect that you describe.  But I think that could be explained as to why the conditional is behaving differently in a lookbehind.

Comment: At this stage I have no idea what you are talking about and I am walking away. Good luck to you.

Comment: I would appreciate, before you walk away, removing the down vote on my answer, because it clearly is a useful answer.  I have been respectful and honest with you in all dealings (something I can't say has been returned).  I have definitely learned something through this discussion as it appears you have also.

Comment: Absolutely no way. My answer is correct. Your answer says that mine is incorrect, therefore your answer is incorrect. And I disagree with your assertion that you have been respectful and honest. (By honest I mean intellectually honest.)

Comment: Thanks. If in your journey you ever hear of a .NET trace tool (like the one that produced the output for PCRE in my answer), I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a great one to dive into lookarounds and lookaheads. It is a rich question, but to me it seems that the main question is this:

**Why does `(?<=(?(?=go)good|bad)\s)morning` fail against "good morning"?**

Because you say "My question is is this expected or some kind of bug?" This is the question I will address.

In a nutshell, at a certain position x in the string, you want to say:

1. If what immediately follows is "go" i.e. `(?=go)` then immediately
   match "morning". Obviously this is incompatible. If you had
   "gorning", you would have a chance. What immediately follows cannot 
   both be "mo" and "go". There is more syntax in that branch, but that is where it fails.
2. Otherwise, (i.e. what follows is not "go"), then if what immediately precedes is "bad ", match "morning". This would match "morning" in "bad morning", but not "good morning".

Therefore the regex cannot match "good morning". QED.

Let's now take a look at a correct program with nearly the same expression. It successfully matches "goodgopher" and "badphilosopher". Once you understand why this works, you will understand why the other does not.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program {
static void Main() {

// Simplest    
string s1 = "badphilosopher";
string s2 = "goodgopher";
string s3 = "badgopher";
string pattern = @"(?<=(?(?=go)good|bad))\w+pher";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s1, pattern) );
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s2, pattern));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s3, pattern));     
Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
} // END Main
} // END Program
```

**The output:**

```
True
True
False
```

The key is to understands that a lookaround asserts: "at this exact position in the string, I am followed (or preceded) by..."

When it is evaluated, the lookaround is firmly in place in one part of the string. If you string several lookarounds in a row, that position does not jump around.

So how does the above regex work?

At the current position in the string, we assert:

```
If at this position in the string, if we are preceded by x
   case 1: if at this position in the string what follows is "go"
           then x is good
   case 2: else
           then x is bad
Then match any number of word characters followed by philosopher
```

To get absolutely clear on lookahead and lookbehind, you may want to read this page about [regex lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

**Sub-Question in Comment:**

`(?<=(?(?=go)good|bad))\s+\w+pher` matches on "bad philosopher" and "bad gopher". Why?

Here is why. In either "bad philosopher" or "bad gopher", place yourself just after the "d". This is your position x. At this position,

1. You can match `\s+\w+pher`, as this is exactly what is in front of you
2. In both cases, a position x, what immediately follows is not "go": right after the "d", in one case what follows is " g", in the other case it is " p" (note the space before the letter). Therefore, for both of those, you are not in the `(?=go)` situation but in the else, and you must assert "What immediately precedes position x is "bad". Is that true? Yes.
3. Therefore the regex can find matches in both strings. QED. But the matches are not found where you expected, but right after the "d".

**But... What Does the Engine Really Do?**

So far, I have not been able to convince the OP about the path taken by the regex engine, so I thought I would paste a trace. Sadly, I do not have a trace tool for .NET regex, but I do have a trace tool for PCRE, an equally if not more potent regex engine.

The trace shows the path of the engine, as reported by pcretest, for the three test strings. Note one tiny difference with the regex in the .NET code supplied above: instead of `good|bad` we have `goo|bad` to accommodate for PCRE's lack of support for variable-length negative lookbehinds.

The trace clearly shows that PCRE evaluates the regex from left to right: first the lookbehind, then the `\w+pher`

I cannot say with 100% certainty that .NET proceeds in the same way, but this has certainly been the standard for regex engine. Of course there is a possibility that engines that support variable-length lookbehinds would proceed differently.

```
PCRE version 8.34 2013-12-15

~(?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))\w+pher~C
badphilosopher
--->badphilosopher
 +0 ^                  (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0  ^                 (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0   ^                (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0    ^               (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +4    ^                                      ^(?(?=go)goo|bad)
 +6    ^                                      ^(?=go)
 +9    ^                                      ^g
+16    ^                                      ^b
+17    ^                                      ^a
+18    ^                                      ^d
+19    ^               )
+20    ^               )
+21    ^               \w+
+24    ^          ^    p
+24    ^         ^     p
+24    ^        ^      p
+24    ^       ^       p
+24    ^      ^        p
+25    ^       ^       h
+26    ^        ^      e
+27    ^         ^     r
+28    ^          ^    
 0: philosopher
googopher
--->googopher
 +0 ^             (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0  ^            (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0   ^           (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0    ^          (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +4    ^                                 ^(?(?=go)goo|bad)
 +6    ^                                 ^(?=go)
 +9    ^                                 ^g
+10    ^                                 ^o
+11    ^                                 ^)
+12    ^                                 ^g
+13    ^                                 ^o
+14    ^                                 ^o
+15    ^          |
+20    ^          )
+21    ^          \w+
+24    ^     ^    p
+24    ^    ^     p
+24    ^   ^      p
+24    ^  ^       p
+24    ^ ^        p
+25    ^  ^       h
+26    ^   ^      e
+27    ^    ^     r
+28    ^     ^    
 0: gopher
badgopher
--->badgopher
 +0 ^             (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0  ^            (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0   ^           (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +0    ^          (?<=(?(?=go)goo|bad))
 +4    ^                                 ^(?(?=go)goo|bad)
 +6    ^                                 ^(?=go)
 +9    ^                                 ^g
+16    ^                                 ^b
+17    ^                                 ^a
+18    ^                                 ^d
+19    ^          )
+20    ^          )
+21    ^          \w+
+24    ^     ^    p
+24    ^    ^     p
+24    ^   ^      p
+24    ^  ^       p
+24    ^ ^        p
+25    ^  ^       h
+26    ^   ^      e
+27    ^    ^     r
+28    ^     ^    
 0: gopher
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I played with your example a bit and when I add spaces between your words (which is more similar to my issue) I get a different result:  (?<=(?(?=go)good|bad))\s+\w+pher matches on "bad philosopher" and "bad gopher".  This is the question.  Why?   Also you say 

"(?=go) then immediately match "morning"."

Which is not what the expression says -- its a conditional - so it means if the following two chars are "go" then match good - otherwise match "bad".

Comment: @user3565980 Okay, that's a great new example, thank you. It's the same logic, and I just answered it now in the bottom of my answer, please see the "Sub-Question in Comment" section. Please let me know if that answers the mystery for you. :)

Comment: Great - now try removing this expression from a look behind and seeing how it matches.   (?(?=go)good|bad)\s+\w+pher   This will now match on all three.   You say above that the regex engine places the lookahead cursor after the "d" in bad.  But why is it not at the beginning of the phrase?

Comment: @user3565980 `You say above that the regex engine places the lookahead cursor after the "d" in bad. But why is it not at the beginning of the phrase?` The regex engine starts at the beginning of the string and tries to match the entire pattern. If fails, so it moves to the next character in the string (after the "b") and tries to match the entire pattern. It fails, so it moves forward, fails, moves forward (after the "d"), tries again and succeeds. That is how a regex engine proceeds. If you only want matches at the beginning of the string, you anchor with `^`. Let me know if this answers it!

Comment: @user3565980 Second part of your question (less important than the comment a few moments ago): yes, `(?(?=go)good|bad)\s+\w+pher` matches all three. The engine starts at the beginning of the string, and in all three cases it is immediately able to match, whether on the `(?=go)` side or on the other side.

Comment: Why would it fail if it started at the beginning of the phrase?  The expression matches the phrase - we can see that when we remove the lookbehind.

Comment: @user3565980 I am not sure which regex you are talking about now. Please take a few minutes to dissect the logic I gave you, it is correct. If you mean "Why does `(?<=(?(?=go)good|bad)\s)morning` fail at the beginning of the string", it is because at the beginning of the string, the following characters are not "morning". To match "morning", the engine would have to move forward in the string.

Comment: @user3565980 This is key to understand: at the beginning of the string, the engine tries to match the **WHOLE** regex. Failure? It moves up one character and tries to match the **WHOLE** regex. Failure?  It moves up one character and tries to match the **WHOLE** regex. At EACH step of trying to match the whole regex, the engine moves in the pattern in parallel to moving in the string. When the process fails at a given starting point, the engine tries again, but with a new starting point, where, once again, it moves in the pattern in parallel to moving in the string.

Comment: Let's simplify by taking out the conditional.  (?<=good\s)morning will match on "morning" only if it is preceded by "good ".  It starts at the beginning of the phrase until it finds morning - and then look backwards until to determine if this morning is preceded by good.

Comment: @user3565980 You say `It starts at the beginning of the phrase until it finds morning` Not exactly. At each position in the string, it will attempt a **WHOLE** match (see comment above). When it starts at the beginning of the string, NO, the engine does not skip until it finds morning. Right there, right now, because it attempts a **WHOLE** match, the first thing it does is try to assert `(?<=good\s)` Obviously this fails. So it moves to the next character, and again tries `(?<=good\s)` The engine does not even attempt to match "morning" until `(?<=good\s)` is satisfied, if ever.

Comment: @user3565980 Wondering if it is clear for you now? I spent over an hour yesterday trying to clarify this for you, would love to hear that it's solved. :)

Comment: I posted an answer - your examples helped me understand what was going on, but your answer wasn't correct.

Comment: @user3565980 My answer is correct. You do not understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your example a little, so that it can be used in PCRE for comparison. PCRE requires a fixed width lookbehind. So both alternatives are 4 characters wide. I've changed the first alternative to match 4 characters `go..` and the second alternative to match any 4 characters `....`.

These are the strings to be matched in the examples. I'm deliberately using underscores instead of spaces for them to show up visibly in capturing groups:

> good_morning
> mild_morning
> cold_morning
> gold_good_morning

---

### No conditional

With almost everything in named capturing groups, it's easier to see what is matched by which part of the expression. First I'll not use a conditional, but an alternation in the lookbehind. The group name `del` is just short for "delimiter":

```regex
(?<= #  either                            or
     ( (?=(?<look>.*)) (?<either>go..) | (?<or>....) ) # $1
     (?<del>.)  # One width character
) 
morning         # The match
```

This matches "morning" on all 4 strings. The interesting bits are what's in the capturing groups. I used [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to get the captured groups:

| Index | Position | Matched String | $1 | ${look} | ${either} | ${or} | ${del} |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | morning | good | good_morning | good | *empty string* | _ |
| 1 | 19 | morning | mild | *empty string* | *empty string* | mild | _ |
| 2 | 33 | morning | cold | *empty string* | *empty string* | cold | _ |
| 3 | 52 | morning | good | good_morning | good | *empty string* | _ |

Since the lookahead is associated with the first alternative, it's no surprise that it's empty when the second alternative is being matched. But when it matches, it matches the entire string. Almost. If `((?<del>.)  # One width character` is changed to `(?<del>.*) # As mush as possible`, the last row becomes:

| Index | Position | Matched String | $1 | ${look} | ${either} | ${or} | ${del} |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 52 | morning | gold | gold_good_morning | gold | *empty string* | _good_ |

It seems as though the lookahead cursor is offset from the main matching regex cursor.

According to Jan Goyvaerts's [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> the JGsoft engine and the .NET framework RegEx classes. These regex engines really apply the regex inside the lookbehind backwards, going through the regex inside the lookbehind and through the subject string from right to left.

and RexEgg.com's [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) when going through the pattern `(?<=(\d{1,5}))Z` on the string "123Z".

> .NET captures *123* to Group 1. The .NET engine has a far more efficient way of processing variable-width lookbehinds. Instead of trying multiple fixed-width patterns starting at points further and further back in the string, .NET reverses the string as well as the pattern inside the lookbehind, then attempts to match that single pattern on the reversed string. Therefore, in *123Z*, to try the lookbehind at the point before *Z*, it reverses the portion of string to be tested from *123* to *321*. Likewise, the lookbehind `(?<=(\d{1,5}))` is flipped into the lookahead `(?=(\d{1,5}))`. `\d{1,5}` matches *321*.

#### Finding the reversed regex

Reversing "good_morning" gives "gninrom_doog". For the regex to match "morning", the main regex cursor must be just between "_" and "m". I'm using a space to illustate between:

```regex
gninrom _doog
       ^
```

Reversing parts of the lookbehind:

```regex
(?=  # lookahead
     (?<del>.)  # One width character
     ...
)
```

The alternation must not have been reversed, since the second alternative matches any 4 characters and if that had been changed to be the first alternative, the groups `look` and `either` would be empty on all matches.

```regex
     ( (?<either>..og) | (?<or>....) )
```

The `look` lookahead captures the entire string including "good", so it can only have become a lookbehind *after* the first alternative:

```regex
     ( (?<either>..og) (?<=(?<look>.*)) | (?<or>....) )
```

That gives:

```regex
(?=  # lookahead
     (?<del>.)  # One width character
     #  either                             or
     ( (?<either>..og) (?<=(?<look>.*)) | (?<or>....) )
)
```

Going through this regex for the reversed string will natually yeild the result seen in the results. Going through it for "gold_good_morning":

```regex
    gninrom _doog_dlog
           ^
```

- The `del` first takes a character, which is the "_"

  ```regex
  gninrom_ doog_dlog
          ^
  ```
- The `either` group captures "doog"

  ```regex
  gninrom_doog _dlog
          ----^
  ```
- The `look` captures the string from the current cursor all the way back:

  ```regex
  gninrom_doog _dlog
  ------------^
  ```
- Once the lookahead (reversed lookbehind) is done, the string and the captures are reversed back.

Adding the Kleene star to `del`, the `(?<del>.*)` will greedily go to the end of the string. Then it will backtrack 4 characters and match `(?<either>..og)` on the string "dlog" before capturing everything into `(?<=(?<look>.*))`.

### Adding the conditional

Adding the conditional instead of just the alternation, putting the lookahead into the condition:

```regex
(?<= #  if             then            else
     (?(?<=(?<if>.*)) (?<then>go..) | (?<else>....) ) 
     (?<del>.)  # One width character
) 
morning         # The match
```

Gives two matches. The condition `if` is always true and the `then`-part only mathes words starting with "go"

| Index | Position | Matched String | ${if} | ${then} | ${else} | ${del} |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 19 | morning | _morning | good | *empty string* | _ |
| 1 | 52 | morning | _morning | good | *empty string* | _ |

Changing the `(?<del>.)  # One width character` to `(?<del>.*) # As mush as possible`, the last row becomes:

| Index | Position | Matched String | ${if} | ${then} | ${else} | ${del} |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 52 | morning | _good_morning | gold | *empty string* | *good* |

The interesting part is the capturing group `if`. It doesn't contains the entire string. That indicates that the conditional isn't reversed by being evaluated last, but instead it is still being evaluated at the beginning of that part of the reserved expression. Though the direction of the lookaround has been reversed:

```regex
(?= (?<del>.)  # One width character
    #  if             then            else
    (?(?<=(?<if>.*)) (?<then>..og) | (?<else>....) ) 
)
```

Looking at how that will process "gold_good_morning", the capturing groups makes sense.

```regex
    gninrom _doog_dlog
           ^
```

- The `del` first takes a character, which is the "_"

  ```regex
  gninrom_ doog_dlog
          ^
  ```
- The `if` lookbehind captures everything from the cursor, which now includes the "_"

  ```regex
  gninrom_ doog_dlog
  --------^
  ```
- Since the condition is true, the `then` part is executed capturing "doog"

  ```regex
  gninrom_doog _dlog
          ----^
  ```

Adding the Kleene star to `del`, the `(?<del>.*)` will again greedily go to the end of the string. But it's forced to backtrack 4 characters for either of `then` or `else` to make a match.

---

### Comparison to PCRE

#### The Alternation

In order for PCRE to accept the alternation as fixed-width, I added a lookahead for the second alternative too:

```regex
(?<= #  either                                  or
     ( (?=(?<lookeither>.*)) (?<either>go..) | (?=(?<lookor>.*)) (?<or>....) ) # $1
     (?<del>.)  # One width character
) 
morning         # The match
```

| Matched String | $1 | lookeither | either | lookor | or | del |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| morning | good | good_morning | good | *null* | *null* | _ |
| morning | mild | *null* | *null* | mild_morning | mild | _ |
| morning | cold | *null* | *null* | cold_morning | cold | _ |
| morning | good | good_morning | good | *null* | *null* | _ |

At [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/byOhot/1)

Instead of reversing the string, it counts back the 5 characters that is to be consumed inside the lookbehind and does its work from here.

Since PCRE doesn't support variable length lookbehinds, it's not possible to use the Kleene star on `del`, but using `(?<del>.{6}) # Fixed six width character` (to account for "_good_") gives one result. It can only give the one result as it has to backtrack a total of 10 characters. Only the string "gold_good_morning" makes that possible:

| Matched String | $1 | lookeither | either | lookor | or | del |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| morning | good | gold_good_morning | good | *null* | *null* | *good* |

#### The Conditional

```regex
(?<= #  if            then            else
     (?(?=(?<if>.*)) (?<then>go..) | (?<else>....) ) 
     (?<del>.) # One width character
) 
morning        # The match
```

gives this:

| Matched String | if | then | else | del |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| morning | good_morning | good | *empty string* | _ |
| morning | good_morning | good | *empty string* | _ |

At [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ph29Wz/1)

Since nothing is reversed, it's working as you expected it to work.

Using `(?<del>.{6}) # Fixed six width character` gives:

| Matched String | if | then | else | del |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| morning | gold_good_morning | gold | *empty string* | _ |

I expect there's no surprises here.

---

### Is it a bug or a feature?

If you want it to give you the same captures as PCRE, then I suppose you could call it a bug. But I'd argue that once you know how it works, you can tailor your expressions to make use of it, and then call it a feature. I'd argue that non-fixed width lookbehinds certainly is a feature.

Knowing that the .NET regex engine reverses the direction of the lookaround, you can simple just reverse the lookaround `look`, so that it's initally opposite. Sort of like backing in reverse is actually going forward :)

```regex
(?<= #  if             then            else
     (?(?<=(?<if>.*)) (?<then>go..) | (?<else>....) ) 
     (?<del>.) # One width character
) 
morning        # The match
```

will give you

| Index | Position | Matched String | ${if} | ${then} | ${else} | ${del} |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 19 | morning | good | good | *empty string* | _ |
| 1 | 52 | morning | gold_good | good | *empty string* | _ |

#### Making your example work

Using your conditional for matching "morning" in "good morning", you can use

```regex
(?<=(?(?<=(go.*))good|bad)\s)morning
```

Obviously `(?<=(go))` won't do, since that would be trying to match "og" against "do" in "doog". But `.*og` is going to match "doog".

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
(?<=(?:(?=\S*\d)[\p{P}\d]+|[A-Z0-9]+)\s)matching text
```

Comment: This didn't match anything for me.. perhaps a different engine?  But remember the question was not how to match the text, but why does the lookahead in the conditional behave differently inside and outside of a lookbehind.

Comment: @user3565980: This pattern was tested with http://regexstorm.net/tester (a tester for .net) with your example strings. About why your pattern doesn't work see my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

We can start with `\s+matching\s+text`.
To eliminate match for `and matching text` and similar we can add negative lookbehind: `(?<!^\s*[A-Z]{3,})`.

To include match for others we can use positive lookbehind:

Match 2-letter patterns: `[A-Z\d]{1,2}`

Match longer patterns: `[-A-Z\d/"']{3,}` <= important, we eliminated strings composed only of letters with negative lookbehind.

Combining together 2 patterns we get the following: `(?<=^\s*([A-Z\d]{1,2}|[-A-Z\d/"']{3,}))`

Full regex would be:

```
(?<!^\s*[A-Z]{3,})(?<=^\s*([A-Z\d]{1,2}|[-A-Z\d/"']{3,}))\s+matching\s+text
```

Comment: Thankyou, this is a really good alternate way of matching this text.  But it doesn't answer the question asked:  Why does a conditional lookahead behave differently inside and outside a lookbehind?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need for lookbehinds here.  Just match the whole string normally and use a capturing group to extract the part that interests you:

```
Regex r = new Regex(
    @"(?imn)^([A-Z0-9]{1,2}\s+|(?![A-Z]+\s)[0-9A-Z/""'-]{3,}\s+)(?<captured>matching\s+text)$");
resultString = r.Match(s).Groups["captured"].Value;
```

Comment: The question isn't if lookbehinds are needed or not.  It is: Why does the lookahead in the conditional behave differently when inside and outside a lookbehind?